# Can IntelliJ IDEA debugger set breakpoints by itself?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to figure out which methods of which class are triggered when i send an api get request to the web application i'm working on. Is it possible to configure the debugger in such a way that it automatically sets a breakpoint at the controller method that is first triggered when sending the api request? For me that would be a quick way to determine where to start my debugging quest. I'm using Java.

Comment: It would be good to know what language or framework you are writing your API

Comment: please see my comment

Answer (score 4):

you can try wildcard method breakpoint for all methods of the handler class, it will trigger on any class method invocation:

- go to breakpoints dialog
- click +
- select "Java method breakpoints"
- enter handler class name and `*` as a method name:
  [image]

Comment: can i use wildcards in the class pattern too? Because i want to add breakpoints to the methods of all classes used and made by me. (no native java files)

Comment: sure, but regular expressions in class pattern are limited to exact matches and patterns that begin with * or end with *, for example, "*.Foo" or "java.*".