# Is there a way to set a breakpoint whenever a file is created in Java, using IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints

After doing a complex build of a multi-module project in IntelliJ, somehow several 0-length files get generated or created somehow. I want to debug the build process and set a conditional breakpoint whenever a file is created with a specific name.  Is there a way to do that?

I tried setting a breakpoint in the File() constructors, but apparently these zero-length files get created without creating a File class instance, because my conditional breakpoint is never hit.  I also tried a breakpoint in File#createNewFile(), but it was never hit.

I even tried creating directories with the names of the 0-length files, so that attempting to create them as files would fail.  After the build, those remained directories, and no exceptions or errors occurred during the build.

This seems like it ought to be possible.  There is too much IntelliJ code and Gradle code and my own application's code to look through and guess where these zero-length files are being created.

Comment: Have you tried to search for the files first? `ctrl + shift + f` and then search by the file name, file constructor (new File(), FileOutputStream, FileWriter, etc)?

Comment: Though you could try to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223299/16034206

Comment: What location are the files created in, and how are they named?

Comment: I am trying to find out the answer.  The files appear after the build is run.  Who creates them?  Where? That's what I want to know.

Comment: Of course I have found the files by name.  They aren't there before the build. They appear after the build.  That's the problem, not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- I think maybe an external static util class create the file, so even you set a breakpoint in `File` but never hit it.
- Some debug advices in this situation:

> a file is created with a specific name

1. since the file name is a specific name, hit shift twice to search this name, you may find it.
2. or the name was constructed by a certain way, such as `20240125.txt`, then search something like `Date+".txt"`
3. check the created time of files, think which part of code may run in that time.

> I tried setting a breakpoint

4. since you can set breakpoint, you can debug the application module by module, check which module/class/method called then the file appears.
5. add a condition breakpoint in a `Interceptor`, check the folder size or file name all the time, if the new file appears then hit it.

Comment: These "answers" miss the entire point of the question. They are a dump of what this person knows.  Where can I set a conditional breakpoint to find all the places that a zero length file might be created?  It could be a command that copies files, for example.

Answer (score -1):

3 methods to create empty file (length of file is 0) in Java, try add breakpoints to them:

1. File.createNewFile()
2. FileOutputStream.write(byte[] b)

```java
    String fileData = "";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
    fos.write(fileData.getBytes());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
```

3. java.nio.Files.write()

```java
    String fileData = "";
    Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), fileData.getBytes());
```

Comment: Actually, what need to do is finding out all methods that can be used to create files in Java as well as other programming languages in your project.

Comment: Yes, that was my question. What are all the ways?  It used to be simple when Java first came out.